# jasmin: mock instance of a class

Tags: javascript, tdd, jasmine

Is it possible to create a mock of an object **obj** such that Jasmine test like

```
expect(fakeB instanceof B).toBe(true);
```

passes?

In other words, I have a class **A** with a method **convertToB** which argument must be an instance of a class **B**:

```
function A(){
  this.convertToB = function(elem){
    if (!(elem instanceof B)){ throw an error}
    ...
    ... 
  }
}
```

I would like to cover with test that piece of code by creating a mock object that when being asked whether it is an instance of **B** would respond **true**.

For the moment I am forced to write tests kind of

1. *it('throws an error if the argument is a string')*
2. *it('throws an error if the argument is an array')*
3. ...

which is a bit annoying. I expect a command like

```
 var fakeB = jasmine.createFake('B')
```

so that the first line of code in this question would pass.

Answer (score 9):

I have dozens of places in my code exactly as yours. spyOn method of Jasmine 2.0 will do the job. Same with Jasmine 1.0 but I don't remember if the method is called/used exactly the same way. To the example:

```
var realB = new B();

// change realB instance into a spy and mock its method 'foo' behaviour to always return 'bar'
// it will still respond "true" to "realB instanceof B"
spyOn(realB, 'foo').and.returnValue('bar')

var realC = new C();

// C.baz is expecting instance of B to be passed as first argument
var result = C.baz(realB)

// assuming C.baz return realB.foo() concatenated with '123'
expect(result).toEqual('bar123');
```

Jasmine documentation has extensive list of examples of spies: http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply! In other words, what you say is that if I create a variable **realB** inizialized by means of **new B()**, this variable will be an instance of **B**. No matter, will one mocks methods of **realB** or not. And this is OK. But in this way the line **if (!(elem instanceof B)){ throw an error}** remains uncovered and to cover it with a test I will have to create a bunch of objects that are not instances of B and pass them to the **convertB** method.

Comment: Yes, mocking methods will not change type.

To cover throwing error you would have to write another test and call method under test passing argument that is not of type B. For example a number, or object literal.

Answer (score 3):

My implementation is as follows:

```js
function proxyConstructor(obj) {
  obj = obj || {};
  for (var key in obj) {
    this[key] = obj[key];
  }

  this.prop = 'runtime prop';
  this.instanceMethod(1);
}

var TestClass = jasmine.createSpy(`TestClass.constructor`).and.callFake(proxyConstructor);
TestClass.prototype.instanceMethod = jasmine.createSpy(`TestClass#instanceMethod`);
TestClass.staticMethod = jasmine.createSpy(`TestClass.staticMethod`);

var ins = new TestClass();
expect(ins).toBe(jasmine.any(TestClass)) // success
expect(ins.prop).toBe('runtime prop'); // success
expect(ins.instanceMethod.toHaveBeenCalledWith(1)) // success
```